# Wanting to add a certain value to each element of a matrix in a unique context

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def increaseEach(arr,n1,n2):
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
            arr[i][0] += n1
            arr[i][1] += n2
    return arr    

while counter0 < count0:
        for y in range(0,5):
            if x % 2 == 0:
                countEven += 1
                for j in crnew:
                    crnew = increaseEach(j,2,-2)
                sc = (crnew[y][0],crnew[y][1])
                ec = (crnew[y+4][0],crnew[y+4][1])
                pg.draw.line(screen,red,sc,ec,1)

            if x % 2 == 1:
                countOdd+= 1
                for j in crnew2:
                    crnew2 = increaseEach(j,2,-2)
                sc2 = (crnew2[y][0],crnew[y][1])
                ec2 = (crnew2[y+4][0],crnew[y+4][1])
                pg.draw.line(screen,red,sc2,ec2,1)
```

crnew and crnew2 are both matrices, j in both of these loops are the individual arrays in crnew and crnew2. I get the following error report:

```
line 144, in <module>
    crnew = increaseEach(j,2,-2)

line 34, in increaseEach
    arr[i][0] += n1

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I am quite confused as to whether or not the source of the bug is in the increaseEach function at line 34 where my function is defined, or later on in my code where I try to use it.
Thanks.

Comment: Seems that the error occurred when you called `increaseEach` on line 144. The error happened specifically during execution of `increaseEach` at line 34.

Comment: Do you by chance know how to resolve that issue of 'int object is not subscriptable'?

Comment: Not specifically in your case, but I would assume that either `arr` or `arr[i]` is actually an `int` and you can't subscript it.

Comment: @JohnGunasar `arr[i][0] += n1` that line is expecting to index a 2-D array, but you possibly have only 1-D array. instead try  `arr[i] += n1`

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: update `crnew2 = increaseEach(j,2,-2)` to `j = increaseEach(j,2,-2)` and `crnew = increaseEach(j,2,-2)` to `j= increaseEach(j,2,-2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were passing the row from the matrix and you want the element in that row to be updated.that is happening correct . when the resultant row(list) come from the function you were saving it in original matrix . which updated the matrix . to single row. ir from `n x m` matrix size it changed to `1x m` size . in next iteration when the element to function instead of whole row (list )a single int variable went , which cause the error that int is not scritable.

you need to update `crnew2 = increaseEach(j,2,-2)` to `j = increaseEach(j,2,-2)` and `crnew = increaseEach(j,2,-2)` to `j= increaseEach(j,2,-2)`

```
def increaseEach(arr,n1,n2):
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
            arr[i][0] += n1
            arr[i][1] += n2
    return arr    

while counter0 < count0:
        for y in range(0,5):
            if x % 2 == 0:
                countEven += 1
                for j in crnew:
                    j = increaseEach(j,2,-2)
                sc = (crnew[y][0],crnew[y][1])
                ec = (crnew[y+4][0],crnew[y+4][1])
                pg.draw.line(screen,red,sc,ec,1)

            if x % 2 == 1:
                countOdd+= 1
                for j in crnew2:
                    j = increaseEach(j,2,-2)
                sc2 = (crnew2[y][0],crnew[y][1])
                ec2 = (crnew2[y+4][0],crnew[y+4][1])
                pg.draw.line(screen,red,sc2,ec2,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you perhaps help me understand the logic of why we update the local array, j, in the loop?

Comment: @JohnGunasar you were passing the row from the matrix and you want the element in that row to be updated.that is happening correct . when the resultant row(list) come from the function you were saving it in original  matrix . which updated the matrix . to single row. ir from n x m matrix size it changed to 1x m size . in next iteration when the element to  function instead of whole row (list )a single int variable went , which cause the error that int is not scritable.

Comment: Ahh okay. Thank you for that very clear explanation!